# Expected Declaration error messages on empty lines

Tags: swift

I am getting an expected declaration error message on two empty lines and do not know how to fix them. I don't understand why it is coming up on an empty line. Here is my code.

```
var RandomValue = arc4random_uniform(15) + 1

var secondRandomValue = arc4random_uniform(15) + 1


var firstNumberLabel: UILabel
   self.firstNumberLabel.text = "\(RandomValue)"
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Your label is not initialized. Skip the `{` and examine the templates from Xcode to see how a label is declared in swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare your `firstNumberLabel` globally into `ViewController` class like this:

```
var firstNumberLabel : UILabel = UILabel()
```

after that you can access it anywhere I have tried something like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var firstNumberLabel : UILabel = UILabel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var RandomValue = arc4random_uniform(15) + 1
    var secondRandomValue = arc4random_uniform(15) + 1
    self.firstNumberLabel.text = "\(RandomValue)"
    }
}
```

May be this can help you.

Comment: Thank you veraabad and Dharmesh Kheni for your help. Both of your suggestions fixed the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Like Mundi said your UILabel is not declared before you are trying to add a string to its text property. Try this.

```
var firstNumberLabel: UILabel!
self.firstNumberLabel.text = "Your string"
```